# Comparar dados de duas tabelas

Tags: php, mysql, sql-select

Tenho duas tabelas:

```
Tabela1                        Tabela2
+------+----------+--------+   +------+----------+------------+ 
|  id  | idCidade | bairro |   |  id  | idBairro | logradouro |
+------+----------+--------+   +------+----------+------------+
| 6091 |   15890  | Vila A |   |  05  |   6091   | Av. Brasil |
| 5089 |   17500  | Vila A |   |  08  |   1000   | Av. Brasil |
+------+----------+--------+   +------+----------+------------+
```

O usuário informara o 'logradouro', 'idCidade'. Preciso saber qual é bairro de determinado logradouro em determinada cidade. Com o nome do 'logradouro' eu busco na Tabela2, no exemplo acima ele me retorna a existência de dois lugares com esse nome em bairros destintos. Mas eu também faço uma busca na Tabela1, busco a 'id' de todos bairros de determinada cidade. Se por exemplo eu informar que (idCidade=17500) e (logradouro=Av Brasil), o bairro desse logradouro seria 'Vila A' de id=5089. Qual seria a query que usaria para isso?

Comment: Seu exemplo não é válido, já que o `idBairro` do segundo logradouro da `Tabela1` é 1000 e não tem nenhum registro com esse valor na `Tabela1`

Comment: @Sorack a `Av. Brasil` pode passar por vários bairro, nota : ele passou um exemplo, não caso real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No caso de uma junção de tabelas você deve utilizar um `JOIN`:

```
SELECT tb1.id,
       tb1.bairro
  FROM Tabela1 tb1
       INNER JOIN Tabela2 tb2 ON tb2.idBairro = tb1.id
 WHERE tb1.idCidade = 17500
   AND tb2.logradouro = 'Av Brasil';
```

Neste caso o `INNER JOIN` irá realizar a junção das tabelas de acordo com o `idBairro`. Do resultado da junção, filtramos de acordo com o código da cidade na `Tabela1` e o logradouro da `Tabela2`;

Caso deseje saber mais sobre o funcionamento do `JOIN`, você pode verificá-lo nesta excelente resposta da pergunta [**Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6448/59479)

---

Observação: No seu exemplo, para que o resultado esperado seja retornado, seria necessário que existisse a seguinte linha na `Tabela2`:

```
 +------+----------+------------+ 
 |  id  | idBairro | logradouro |
 +------+----------+------------+
 |  12  |   5089   | Av. Brasil |
 +------+----------+------------+
```

Comment: Parceiro, deu certinho como me passou, obg. Vou dar uma aprofundada nesse assunto rs.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM bairro left join logradouro  
on (bairro.id = logradouro.idBairro)
and (logradouro.logradouro like '%Av Brasil%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Ja monteu sistema de endereço assim, o relacionamento é bem simples, basta interligar via id das tabelas, que o próprio SGBD vai criar novas linhas pra cada endereço diferente.

```
SELECT
    cidade,
    bairro,
    logradouro
FROM
    logradouro L
    LEFT JOIN bairro B ON B.idBairro = L.idBairro
    LEFT JOIN cidade C ON C.idCidade = B.idCidade
WHERE
    B.idCidade = 17500 AND
    logradouro = 'Av Brasil'
```

Usei diretamente o nome das tabelas que eu pressuponho que você use.

Comment: Usei a sua, e me apareceu _Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'cidade' in field list is ambiguous'_
Você usou o nome das tabelas corretamente como esta aqui também. Outra coisa, eu consegui com um ex-colega essa tabela de CEP's, e todas as ids ja estão interligadas.

Comment: Parceiro, consegui com a query do sorack. Mas a sua me ajudou muito a intender antes de ver a dele. Agradeço muito!